# Property path can't find reference

Tags: wpf

What's the syntax for the property path to find the color property of the second gradientStop?

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
     <RadialGradientBrush>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD0D0D0" Offset="0.992" />
     </RadialGradientBrush>
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

I tried `New PropertyPath("Fill.RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops[1].Color")` but it could find the color property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `Fill` property *is* the `RadialGradientBrush`.  The brush is not a member of Fill.

Try `PropertyPath("Fill.GradientStops[1].Color")`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be :

```
(Fill as RadialGradientBrush).GradientStops[1].Color
```

Because RadialGradientBrush is not a property, but a class